# Dataflow job fails without proper error when implemented in VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to run a dataflow job and to do this I am using dataflow template Cloud Spanner to text file on Cloud Storage. My dataflow is on a shared VPC but both &Spanner is not a resource which is on VPC. This job fails but there is no proper error message when it fails. I tried to clone the same job and run this on default VPC then things seems to work and job was successful. Can someone help me understand what is going on and where i should look? Is there an issue for dataflow to communicate with Spanner? If so is there a resource which could help to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you at least get any Dataflow worker logs? Or does the job fail after 1 hour with a generic message that workers were not reachable? Please take a look here for possible issues https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout

Comment: No it fails within a minute. If we run on default vpc it takes around 3.5mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure the following is met -

> The Shared VPC network that you select is an auto mode network.

> You are a Service Project Admin with project-level permissions to the whole Shared VPC host project. This means that a Shared VPC Admin has granted you the Compute Network User role for the whole host project, so you are able to use all of its networks and subnetworks.

Ref - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#network_parameter